# Issue with my doc file downloading script in PHP

Tags: php

I have a doc file generating from my server and it should be downloaded automatically.I have the code like

```
public static function downloadDoc(){
        $file='coverletter/Myprofile.docx';
        if(file_exists($file))
    {
        header('Content-Description:FileTransfer');
        header('Content-Type:application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary');
        header('Expires:0');
        header('Cache-control:must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma:public');
        header('Content-length:'.filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);    
    }
    }
```

I have a form with some basic details to generate the  doc file.After submitting the form , saving to the database. Then I am setting a  flash message to the client like

```
 <?php
      if (isset($_SESSION['flash'])) {
        ?>
         <div class="alert alert-success">
            <?=$_SESSION['flash']?>
         </div>
     <?php
         session_destroy();
         DocManager::generateDoc();
         DocManager::downloadDoc();
    }
?>
```

The code is working fine. But the issue when I call the above download function flash message not working, I mean the form not resetting to blank, it will remain old data entered by the user.When i comment the download function , then the rest working perfectly.

I think the download script preventing the page to execute further.How can i solve this issue.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The output buffer must be started by ob_start(). Otherwise ob_clean() will not work. Your code should look like this

```
public static function downloadDoc(){
    $file='coverletter/Myprofile.docx';
    if(file_exists($file))
{
    ob_start();
    header('Content-Description:FileTransfer');
    header('Content-Type:application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary');
    header('Expires:0');
    header('Cache-control:must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma:public');
    header('Content-length:'.filesize($file));
    ob_get_clean();
    readfile($file);    
}
}
```

If you want to destroy the buffer you can try ob_end_clean or ob_clean instead of ob_get_clean